# Problema con el proceso de autenticación de la API REST de Shopify en PHP

Tags: php, api, rest, jwt, shopify

Me encuentro trabajando en una aplicación personalizada para una tienda en Shopify. Este algoritmo que me encuentro haciendo debe estar realizado en PHP. La documentación de la que me estoy guiando, se encuentra [acá](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest#authentication). Como lo indica en el ejemplo de autenticación, estoy usando este código:

```
$session = Shopify\Utils::loadCurrentSession(
  $headers,
  $cookies,
  $isOnline
);

$client = new Rest(
  $session->getShop(),
  $session->getAccessToken()
);

$response = $client->get('shop');
```

Los valores de las variables `$headers, $cookies y $isOnline` son los siguientes:

```
    $headers =  array(
        "Accept" => "application/json",
        "Authorization" => "Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN",
        "api_version" => "2023-07",
        "X-Shopify-Access-Token" => "ACCESS_TOKEN"
    );

    $cookies = array();
    $isOnline = false;
```

El problema está en que en la documentación el indica que este ACCESS_TOKEN debe ser enviado mediante la cabecera `X-Shopify-Access-Token`, pero cuando esta es enviada de esa manera (Sin la cabecera Authorization), da un error indicando que la cabecera Authorization esta ausente, pude observar que la cabecera `X-Shopify-Access-Token` no esta siendo reconocida en la petición.

Por otra parte, cuando esta es enviada de esta manera, da un error diferente el cual dice lo siguiente: `Key material must be a string, resource, or OpenSSLAsymmetricKey` ahi estoy colocando el ACCESS_TOKEN que me provee shopify pero por lo que comprendo el esta esperando un token JWT, a lo cual intente generarlo y pasarlo por ahi, pero me sigue dando error.

Agradezco sus aportes.